# Combining two Rows together whilst maintaining initial data

Tags: r, dataframe

I am struggling to combine two data frames together - both consisting of only one column, however, with different lengths.

My first data Frame, called 'FamilyID' looks as such:

```
FamilyID <- structure(list(Family_No = c(1034, 1056, 1064, 1091, 1101, 1101, 
11, 113, 113, 1133, 1133, 115, 116)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My second data frame, called 'FID', looks as such:

```
FID <- structure(list(Family_No = c(1034, 1034, 1056, 1056, 1064, 1064, 
1091, 1091, 1101, 1101, 11, 11, 113, 113)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So as you can see, they are very similar, the second one is simply a duplicate of the first one - but I now need to combine them into one column but MAINTAIN all the initial values, so that I have 3 or 4 of every individual value (e.g. for the first value 1034, I have one of them in the first data frame and two of them in the second data frame, so ultimately want three of them in the final data frame). I know with merge, the duplicates will be eliminated, but I need to keep all the values. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Use `rbind`.  If colnames are different, use it with `setNames`

Comment: Isn't this a simple `rbind` ? `rbind(FamilyID, FID)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line of code:

```
new_df <- data.frame(Family_No = cbind(c(FamilyID$Family_No, FID$Family_No)))
```

data:

```
# dataframe 1
FamilyID <- structure(list(Family_No = c(1034, 1056, 1064, 1091, 1101, 1101, 
11, 113, 113, 1133, 1133, 115, 116)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# dataframe 2
FID <- structure(list(Family_No = c(1034, 1034, 1056, 1056, 1064, 1064, 
1091, 1091, 1101, 1101, 11, 11, 113, 113)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Output:

```
> new_df
   Family_No
1       1034
2       1056
3       1064
4       1091
5       1101
6       1101
7         11
8        113
9        113
10      1133
11      1133
12       115
13       116
14      1034
15      1034
16      1056
17      1056
18      1064
19      1064
20      1091
21      1091
22      1101
23      1101
24        11
25        11
26       113
27       113
```

Comment: This worked! I have my output that looks like yours. Is there a way for me to now rearrange my data so that the matching values line up with one another? I ultimately need my data (this one column) to like like so:

1034
1034
1034
1056
1056
1056
1064
1064
1064
1091
1091
1091
1101
1101
1101
1101
etc.

Comment: You can sort with `sort(new_df[,1], decreasing = TRUE)`. This sorts the column in decreasing order.

Answer (score 0):

Can also place the datasets (with single column) in a `list` and `unlist` to create a `vector`, then wrap with `data.frame`

```
data.frame(Family_No = unlist(list(FamilyID, FID)))
```